# Spring Data Repository for Inheritance.JOINED subclass with PrimaryKeyJoinColumn and Composite Key in Super

Tags: java, inheritance, spring-data, eclipselink

I have two entities that map to two DB tables. One inherits from the other. The subclass also shares a composite foreign key with the parent.

**Foo Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@IdClass(FooKey.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator_flag", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
@DiscriminatorValue("F")
@Customizer(FooCustomizer.class)
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_col_1")
    private String idCol1;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_col_2")
    private String idCol2;
    ...
}
```

**Bar Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({ @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "foo_id_col_1", referencedColumnName = "id_col_1"), @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "foo_id_col_2", referencedColumnName = "id_col_2") })
public class Bar extends Foo {
    ...
}
```

**Foo Repository**

```
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, FooKey> {
}
```

**Bar Repository**

```
public interface BarRepository extends CrudRepository<Bar, FooKey> {
}
```

The `FooRepository` works like a charm. No problems. But the `BarRepository` causes an exception in EclipseLink 2.5.2 (Spring-data 1.7.2.RELEASE)

```
No @IdClass attributes exist on the IdentifiableType [EntityTypeImpl@28997437:Bar [ javaType: class com.example.Bar descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.example.Bar --> [DatabaseTable(foo), DatabaseTable(bar)]), mappings: 49]].  There still may be one or more @Id or an @EmbeddedId on type.
```

I tried adding an `@IdClass(FooKey.class)` annotation to Bar but it complains that it can't see the matching @Id fields on the entity (of course they are on the super class)

Anyone have any ideas how to implement a BarRepository successfully for this?

**UPDATE**

I believe this to be a problem with EclipseLink and its handling of composite keys in an inheritance structure. I tried doing this with a MappedSuperclass and moved the key and common items out of `Foo` into `AbstractFoo` and found that both concrete implementations of it (`Foo` and `Bar`) both threw the error. Adding in the @IdClass annotation onto both as a workaround proved just as useless.

What did work was removing the composite key and replacing it with a simple single property @Id. Everything just worked normally.

So faced with the option of refactoring everything to use a single key and then enforcing a unique constraint on my two composite key columns at the database level or removing the inheritance and applying a `@OneToOne` mapping from Bar to Foo with `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns` and cascading all operations, I went with the cop-out option 2. So my `Bar` entity now looks like

**Bar Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
@IdClass(BarKey.class)
public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo_id_col_1")
    private String fooIdCol1;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo_id_col_2")
    private String fooIdCol2;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({ @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "foo_id_col_1", referencedColumnName = "id_col_1"), @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "foo_id_col_2", referencedColumnName = "id_col_2") })
    Private Foo foo;
    ...
}
```

Now my `BarRepository` works fine with the caveat that I have to create a `Foo` entity and attach it to a `Bar` entity before I persist. For me this was far, far less work.

Comment: Bar extends Foo, so it shouldn't need its own repository should it?  Turn on EclipseLink logging to finest and see what the persistence unit it loading.  Make sure that the Bar and Foo entities are in the same persistence unit, and that both are found.

Comment: It will do. Alternatively I could have a T extends Foo repository but same problem.